# Table schema for Shiro JdbcRealm Authorization?

Tags: java, authorization, shiro, jdbcrealm

I would like my app to use [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) for both authentication and authorization. I would like to start simple and have a relational database be the data source for both of these. This means I need to use the [JdbcRealm](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.3/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/realm/jdbc/JdbcRealm.html).

After reading the docs, it is not clear to me what table schema is required for any "user tables", including any tables that link users to their permissions/roles.

So I ask: **using Shiro's `JdbcRealm`, how/where do I link user's to their respective permissions/roles?**

It can't be in the `shiro.ini` file because that is a static config file and wouldn't be feasible for connecting to a JDBC data source where users info is stored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [JdbcRealm](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.3/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/realm/jdbc/JdbcRealm.html) doesn't depend on a specific table schema: it uses some default queries which you can override (either by subclassing or by means of specific setter methods) in order to adapt it to your needs.

As stated in the [javadoc](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.3/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/realm/jdbc/JdbcRealm.html), you can use the default queries as a base for building your own schema. Having a look at the [source](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.3/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/shiro/realm/jdbc/JdbcRealm.html#line.61), you may start creating three basic tables: `users`, `user_roles` and `roles_permissions`.

```
protected static final String DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_QUERY = "select password from users where username = ?";

/**
* The default query used to retrieve account data for the user when {@link #saltStyle} is COLUMN.
*/
protected static final String DEFAULT_SALTED_AUTHENTICATION_QUERY = "select password, password_salt from users where username = ?";

/**
* The default query used to retrieve the roles that apply to a user.
*/
protected static final String DEFAULT_USER_ROLES_QUERY = "select role_name from user_roles where username = ?";

/**
* The default query used to retrieve permissions that apply to a particular role.
*/
protected static final String DEFAULT_PERMISSIONS_QUERY = "select permission from roles_permissions where role_name = ?";
```

Comment: Thanks @Cristian Greco - nailed it!